# Smart cast to 'CredentialsClient!' is impossible following turtorial

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

I am following the tutorial to add the recommended authentication methodology, but I get this error:

> Smart cast to 'CredentialsClient!' is impossible, because 'mCredentialsClient' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Following the tutorial [Smart Lock for Passwords on Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials#request_stored_credentials)

I am also trying to use Kotlin (Android's recommended dev language too)

Here is my code:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.*
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task


class new_MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    var mCredentialsClient: CredentialsClient? = null
    var mCredentialRequest: CredentialRequest? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_login)

        mCredentialsClient = Credentials.getClient(this)

        mCredentialRequest = CredentialRequest.Builder()
                .setPasswordLoginSupported(true)
                .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
                .build()

        mCredentialsClient.request(mCredentialRequest).addOnCompleteListener(
                object : OnCompleteListener<CredentialRequestResponse?>() {
                    fun onComplete(@NonNull task: Task<CredentialRequestResponse?>) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // See "Handle successful credential requests"
                            onCredentialRetrieved(task.getResult().getCredential())
                            return
                        }

                        // See "Handle unsuccessful and incomplete credential requests"
                        // ...
                    }
                })


    }

    private fun onCredentialRetrieved(credential: Any) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you define mCredentialsClient a nullable variable by using ? operator.
so every time you want to use mCredentialsClient you should check if it is null or not.
to do this before using mCredentialsClient field you can say :

```
if(mCredentialsClient != null){
//send request
}
```

or if you want to handle it in kotlin way use 'let' function like this:

```
mCredentialsClient?.let{
        it.request
    }
```

here you are checking if mCredentialsClient is null or not, if mCredentialsClient is null nothing will happen, but if mCredentialsClient is not null, the function inside curly braces will be executed.
notice that inside the block of let function you will use

> it

as

> mCredentialsClient

Comment: thank you very much. I will give that a try and follow up if needed.